# Difference between a WCF service and a ASP.NET web service.?

Tags: web-services, wcf

What's the basic difference beween a WCF service and an ASP.NET web service? How is a WCF service much more advantageous over a web service? And what should be the basis to decide which one should be used in a particular scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Try out this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa738737%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
This is wonderful briefing from microsoft.